# ODBC DSN not found, but the dsn exists

Tags: powershell, odbc

I'm trying to set up an ODBC connection via DSN

I'm setting it up via powershell like this:

```
Add-OdbcDsn -Name "sql2" -DriverName "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server" -SetPropertyValue @("Server=myserver", "Trusted_Connection=No", "Database=mydb") -DsnType "System" -Platform "64-bit"
```

When I run "Get-ODBCDsn" I get the following:

```
Name       : sql2
DsnType    : System
Platform   : 64-bit
DriverName : ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
Attribute  : {Database, Server, Trusted_Connection}
```

which checks out and is correct

I use the following code to test the connection:

```
$connectionString = 'DSN(sql)';
$conn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection($connectionString);
$conn.Open();
```

However I get the following error even though the DSN is clearly there:

```
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"
```

At line:1 char:1

- $conn.Open();

I've also tried setting it to 32 bit like this:

```
Add-OdbcDsn -Name "sql32" -DriverName "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server" -SetPropertyValue @("Server=myserver", "Trusted_Connection=No", "Database=mydb") -DsnType "System" -Platform "32-bit"
```

and getting the same result, and I've succesfully connected to the database by crafting the connection string manually, whats going on here?